How do I manually finalize a 22.04 to 24.04 upgrade that failed?
I ran do-release-upgrade to move 22.04 to 24.04 and it didn't work. It kicked out with lots of dependency errors and a 'your system may be in an unusable state' warning. Nothing else could be installed, updated or repaired with apt because of dependency problems.
By manually downloading the 24.04 libglib2.0 deb and forcing it to install I was able to get apt update/upgrade/autoremove to work which I assume has me mostly covered in terms of package updates. After that I found my networking was failing because resolv.conf was empty. systemd-resolved was missing so I installed that manually and now everything seems to be working.
A missing systemd-reolved is really obvious but now I'm wondering if the failed upgrade left me without any other packages that should be present on a properly installed 24.04, or if there is anything else the do-release-upgrade would have done that I can do manually to make sure the upgrade process is complete. Is there a checklist of do-release-upgrade's wrapup processes I can run through, or an easy way to do a diff of installed packages between my system and a 'clean' 24.04?
